# Clone image from different row in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have this table structure here:

```
<table id="all-prods" class="table bordered">
  <tbody>    
    <tr class="product">
      <td>
        <img src="test" />
      </td>
      <td>Product Title</td>
      <td style="text-align:right">
        <button type="button" name="click_me">Check out the Variants!</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="display:none">
      <td><b>Variant:</b></td>
      <td><b>Price:</b></td>
      <td><b>Quantity:</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-odd" style="display:none">
      <td>Variant title</td>
      <td>Variant price</td>
      <td style="text-align:right;">
        <input id="variant-x" class="quantity field"/>
        <button style="text-align:right" type="button" name="addItem">Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It's designed to be 1 row for each product , with subrows for each variant.
The contents of this table are being cloned to this one:

```
<table id="items" class="table bordered hidden">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item image:</th>
      <th>Item:</th>
      <th>Price:</th>
      <th>Quantity:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I can clone the variant's data with this script here:

```
<script>
  var clone = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
  clone.appendTo('#items tbody');
</script>
```

Thing is.. I can't find a way to copy the product's image as the first column in the second table.

I've tried this:**Updated** [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ra8rc1gk/29/) approach but it seems like I'm failing to find the element.

**Update**
Script at the moment looks like this:

```
$("button[name='addItem']").click(function(){
    var clone = $(this).closest('tr').clone(true);
    var img = $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('img').clone(true);
    img = img.wrap("<td></td>");
    img.prependTo(clone);
    clone.appendTo('#items tbody');
  })
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prev()` method checks for exactly previous element. Use  `prevAll('.product:first')` for getting the product row reference and then use `find('img')[0].outerHTML` to `img`'s html. Try like following.

```
$("button[name='addItem']").click(function () {
    var clone = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    clone.prepend('<td>' + $(this).closest('tr').prevAll('.product:first').find('img')[0].outerHTML + '</td>')
    clone.appendTo('#wholesale-items tbody');
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ra8rc1gk/35/)**

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll correct the html. It's going to another table instead of a div. Edit: It's been corrected.

Comment: There is just one issue I just found. The image copied is from the first product. Is there a way to fetch the current product's image?

Comment: Use `prevAll('.product:first')` instead of `prevAll('.product:last')`. See update. @Onilol

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("button[name='add-me']").click(function(){
  var $image = $(this).closest("tr").prev("tr").find('img').clone();
  $('#div-test').html($image); 
});
```